# Query to get the output as shown in designation table

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot

```
EmpId EmpDeptName
1   Account
2   Sales
3   IT
4   HR
```

i want output in the format

```
EmpId Account Sales IT HR 
 1 
 2 
 3 
 4
```

If anybody knows how to write query to get this output , please provide me that query.

Comment: you should provide some more details. from which tables do you want to get this information?

Answer (score 0):

This type od data transformation is a `PIVOT`, where you take row data and convert it to columns.

You did not provide many details, but if you wanted the count of employees in each department, you could use something like this:

```
select Account, Sales, IT, HR
from 
(
  select EmpDeptName
  from employees
) d
pivot
(
  count(EmpDeptName)
  for EmpDeptName in (Account, Sales, IT, HR)
) p;
```

This will display the total number of employees in each department as column data instead of rows.